# Unable to connect to web server IIS Express - ASP.NET CORE

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, .net-core, iis-express

My team has developed a asp.net core application in a windows vm on their macbook. I have a windows machine so, *I was asked to update the **App URL** and **Launch browser** from localhost to my windows IP address*. However, when I try to run the application it throws error and says 'Unable to connect to web server IIS Express'.

I've tried to run visual studio as administrator but still the error doesn't seems to go away. I'm attaching the screenshot for the reference. I would appreciate any help thank you.

[image]

By the way here's how my **program.cs** file look like.

```
    public class Program
    {
        /// <summary>
        /// Thread Main.
        /// </summary>
        /// <param name="args">Command Line args.</param>
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            // Configuration builder to load ASPNETCORE env variables
            var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
                .SetBasePath(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory())
                .AddEnvironmentVariables(prefix: "ASPNETCORE_")
                .Build();

            // WebHost Configuration
            // var host = WebHost.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)

            var host = MfHostBuilder.CreateHostBuilder(args).UseConfiguration(config)
               // .UseUrls("http://0.0.0.0:7785")
                .UseStartup<Startup>()
                //.UseKestrel()
                .Build();

            // Start and run the host.
            host.Run();
        }
    }
}
```

and here's my **startup.cs** file looks like.

```
public class Startup : IntegrationService
{
    public override void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        services.AddTransient<GenetecServerControllerOptions>();
        services.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureGenetecServerControllerOptions>();
        services.AddGenetec();
        services.AddSingleton<ServerProcessorOptions>();
        services.ConfigureOptions<ConfigureServerProcessorOptions>();
        base.ConfigureServices(services);
    }
}
```

Comment: Are you just trying to run the app locally on your machine?

Comment: yes @MattB I'm trying to run the app locally on my windows machine.

Comment: Run some diagnostics and edit your question to include the report, https://docs.jexusmanager.com/tutorials/vs-diagnostics.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add IIS integration into your app, this will configure what is required for IIS: This is what I have and use in my Program.cs

```
return Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
        .ConfigureWebHostDefaults(webBuilder => {
            webBuilder.UseContentRoot(Directory.GetCurrentDirectory());
            webBuilder.UseIISIntegration();
            webBuilder.UseStartup<Startup>();
        });
```

Comment: In the Program.cs, you can take a look at this, its a bit old, but you will get the idea. https://stackify.com/how-to-deploy-asp-net-core-to-iis/

Comment: Atif, I've tried, but it didn't work. it throws the same error again.

Comment: Have you created an empty new asp.net core application to see if that works? Also what is MfHostBuilder ?

Comment: return? return where and what? I don't see how this could have solved it. Besides, most wep apps already have the Builder consumed such as var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
I am using ASP Core 6