# Getting 503 error after calling ASP.NET Core Web API .Net 7

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core, asp.net-web-api

I have an ASP.NET Core Web API app that targets .Net 7.0. I'm using Azure SQL DB on the backend and EF Core. When running the app locally using Kestrel it all works flawlessly. However, when I run it locally using IIS Express it will fail after the first call from Postman with a 503. I've tried to locate the root of the issue and found that the offending code is somewhere in the below but can't pinpoint it.

If I change the call to FirstOrDefaultAsync to a synchronous method FirstOrDefault, then I can call this endpoint like 5 times before it fails. If I then comment out the line 'jsonSchema = JsonSchema.Parse(jSchemaDm.Schema);', then I can smash that Send button on Postman all day long without an issue.

Interestingly enough, I also have an ASP.Net Core Web App that is also getting 503s using IIS Express.

```
public async Task<List<ValidatedJson>> ValidateJson(string[] jsonFiles, string schemaType, IMemoryCache memoryCache)
{
    //schemaType must = either "Policy" or "Claim"

    var adminDbContext = new AdminDbContext();
    var jSchemaDm = new JsonSchemaDm();

    var schema = memoryCache.Get(schemaType);
    if (schema == null)
    {
        //jSchemaDm = adminDbContext.JsonSchemaDms.FirstOrDefault(c => c.SchemaType == schemaType);
        jSchemaDm = await adminDbContext.JsonSchemaDms.FirstOrDefaultAsync(c => c.SchemaType == schemaType);
        var cacheEntryOptions = new MemoryCacheEntryOptions
        {
            AbsoluteExpiration = DateTime.Now.AddMinutes(15),
            SlidingExpiration = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(15),
            Size = 1024,
        };
        memoryCache.Set(schemaType, jSchemaDm, cacheEntryOptions);
    }
    else
    {
        jSchemaDm = (JsonSchemaDm)schema;
    }
    
    JsonSchema jsonSchema = new JsonSchema();

    IList<string> messages = new List<string>();
    var validatedJsons = new List<ValidatedJson>();

    try
    {
        jsonSchema = JsonSchema.Parse(jSchemaDm.Schema);

        bool valid = false;
        int msgCount = 0;
        
        foreach (var line in jsonFiles)
        {
            if (line.Length> 0)
            {
                msgCount++;
                try
                {
                    var ojson = JObject.Parse(line);
                    //Validate the policy JSON against the schema
                    valid = ojson.IsValid(jsonSchema, out messages);
                    validatedJsons.Add(new ValidatedJson { IsValid = valid, JsonMessage = line, Messages = messages, JsonMessageNumber = msgCount });
                }
                catch (Exception ex) 
                {
                    //The JSON is not well-formed
                    messages.Add(ex.Message.TrimStart().TrimEnd());
                    validatedJsons.Add(new ValidatedJson { IsValid = false, JsonMessage = line, Messages = messages, JsonMessageNumber = msgCount });
                }
            }
        }
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        messages.Add(ex.Message.TrimStart().TrimEnd());
        validatedJsons.Add(new ValidatedJson { IsValid = false, Messages = messages, ServiceError = ex.Message });
    }

    return validatedJsons;
}
```

Comment: How large are the schemas? Are you overwhelming the memory of the process?

Comment: In Program.cs, you have to configure iis and kestrel: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62571529/unable-to-connect-to-web-server-iis-express-asp-net-core

Comment: @DavidL The schemas are quite large ~650KB (and that's why I cache them after the first retrieval). However, I also have a web app that experiences similar 503s and it doesn't load the schemas.

Comment: It is going to be impossible to tell from this snippet. You need to look at dumps from your process and any logs from global log handlers as well.

Comment: @DavidL I'm not sure where to view those. I check event viewer and there's nothing there.

Comment: Update: I've narrowed it down to Entity Framework Core. I replaced the EF code with good ol' ADO.Net and the 503s went away. I have another app that experiences similar issues that uses EF Core as well but I'm reluctant to rewrite the entire thing.

Comment: That seems like a lot of processing you're doing within an end point. Have you considered processing elsewhere and just get the results of that? I also think you're hitting a resource wall.